# Unsure how to add a jquery media query

Tags: jquery

Im using a sticky sidebar plugin [from this tutorial](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/) but I only want the sidebar to be sticky on desktop size screens. What is the best way of adding a media query into this code so that it only fires for 960px +

```
(function() {

      var $, win;

      $ = this.jQuery;

      win = $(window);

      $.fn.stick_in_parent = function(opts) {
        var elm, inner_scrolling, offset_top, parent_selector, sticky_class, _fn, _i, _len;
        if (opts == null) {
          opts = {};
        }
        sticky_class = opts.sticky_class, inner_scrolling = opts.inner_scrolling, parent_selector = opts.parent, offset_top = opts.offset_top;
        if (offset_top == null) {
          offset_top = 0;
        }
        if (parent_selector == null) {
          parent_selector = void 0;
        }
        if (inner_scrolling == null) {
          inner_scrolling = true;
        }
        if (sticky_class == null) {
          sticky_class = "is_stuck";
        }
        _fn = function(elm, padding_bottom, parent_top, parent_height, top, height, float) {
          var bottomed, detach, fixed, last_pos, offset, parent, recalc, recalc_and_tick, spacer, tick;
          parent = elm.parent();
          if (parent_selector != null) {
            parent = parent.closest(parent_selector);
          }
          if (!parent.length) {
            throw "failed to find stick parent";
          }
          fixed = false;
          spacer = $("<div />");
          recalc = function() {
            var border_top, padding_top, restore;
            border_top = parseInt(parent.css("border-top-width"), 10);
            padding_top = parseInt(parent.css("padding-top"), 10);
            padding_bottom = parseInt(parent.css("padding-bottom"), 10);
            parent_top = parent.offset().top + border_top + padding_top;
            parent_height = parent.height();
            restore = fixed ? (fixed = false, elm.insertAfter(spacer).css({
              position: "",
              top: "",
              width: ""
            }), spacer.detach(), true) : void 0;
            top = elm.offset().top - parseInt(elm.css("margin-top"), 10) - offset_top;
            console.log("setting top", top);
            height = elm.outerHeight(true);
            float = elm.css("float");
            spacer.css({
              width: elm.outerWidth(true),
              height: height,
              display: elm.css("display"),
              "vertical-align": elm.css("vertical-align"),
              float: float
            });
            if (restore) {
              return tick();
            }
          };
          recalc();
          if (height === parent_height) {
            return;
          }
          bottomed = false;
          last_pos = void 0;
          offset = offset_top;
          tick = function() {
            var css, delta, scroll, will_bottom, win_height;
            scroll = win.scrollTop();
            if (last_pos != null) {
              delta = scroll - last_pos;
            }
            last_pos = scroll;
            if (fixed) {
              will_bottom = scroll + height + offset > parent_height + parent_top;
              if (bottomed && !will_bottom) {
                bottomed = false;
                elm.css({
                  position: "fixed",
                  bottom: "",
                  top: offset
                }).trigger("sticky_kit:unbottom");
              }
              if (scroll < top) {
                fixed = false;
                offset = offset_top;
                if (float === "left" || float === "right") {
                  elm.insertAfter(spacer);
                }
                spacer.detach();
                css = {
                  position: "",
                  width: "",
                  top: ""
                };
                elm.css(css).removeClass(sticky_class).trigger("sticky_kit:unstick");
              }
              if (inner_scrolling) {
                win_height = win.height();
                if (height > win_height) {
                  if (!bottomed) {
                    offset -= delta;
                    offset = Math.max(win_height - height, offset);
                    offset = Math.min(offset_top, offset);
                    if (fixed) {
                      elm.css({
                        top: offset + "px"
                      });
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            } else {
              if (scroll > top) {
                fixed = true;
                css = {
                  position: "fixed",
                  top: offset
                };
                css.width = elm.width() + "px";
                elm.css(css).addClass(sticky_class).after(spacer);
                if (float === "left" || float === "right") {
                  spacer.append(elm);
                }
                elm.trigger("sticky_kit:stick");
              }
            }
            if (fixed) {
              if (will_bottom == null) {
                will_bottom = scroll + height + offset > parent_height + parent_top;
              }
              if (!bottomed && will_bottom) {
                bottomed = true;
                if (parent.css("position") === "static") {
                  parent.css({
                    position: "relative"
                  });
                }
                return elm.css({
                  position: "absolute",
                  bottom: padding_bottom,
                  top: ""
                }).trigger("sticky_kit:bottom");
              }
            }
          };
          recalc_and_tick = function() {
            recalc();
            return tick();
          };
          detach = function() {
            win.off("scroll", tick);
            $(document.body).off("sticky_kit:recalc", recalc_and_tick);
            elm.off("sticky_kit:detach", detach);
            elm.css({
              position: "",
              bottom: "",
              top: ""
            });
            parent.position("position", "");
            if (fixed) {
              elm.insertAfter(spacer).removeClass(sticky_class);
              return spacer.remove();
            }
          };
          win.on("scroll", tick);
          win.on("resize", recalc_and_tick);
          $(document.body).on("sticky_kit:recalc", recalc_and_tick);
          elm.on("sticky_kit:detach", detach);
          return setTimeout(tick, 0);
        };
        for (_i = 0, _len = this.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
          elm = this[_i];
          _fn($(elm));
        }
        return this;
      };


    }).call(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do. 
First take a look at [Enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/). It is a library that will handle the media queries. 
When you download it, you can use it like this to call your `$("#sticky_item").stick_in_parent()` function.

`enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 960px)", {` 
    `match : function() {` 
        `// This function is called when the max-width is less than or equal to 960px` 
    `},`  
    `unmatch : function() {` 
        `// This function is called when the max-width is greater than 960px` 
`$("#sticky_item").stick_in_parent();` 
    `}` 
`});`